# using the pandas library with influxdb database how do you choose which columns are measurements tags fields etc

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

Trying to use influxdb with pandas however I am unable to work out how you add a dataframe to an influxdb database and in doing so choose which columns of your dataframe should be the measurements, tags and or fields?

Comment: This question is a bit hard to answer simply because of how general it is. Can you include a bit more about your specific use case? In general fields should be numerical/boolean values, tags are indexed values and can only ever be strings, measurements are like buckets used for labelling what they contain.

Comment: Michael I'm sorry it's general for a reason. I understand some of the ideal data types for the specific fields in influx db what I don't understand and why I specially made this question general is if you can tell influx db when you pass a dataframe which columns you want to be field sets and what you want to be field sets and which column you want for a measurement. Or if you can't specify this and you just have to leave it up to pandas influx db library to decide what are your tags etc

Comment: Which pandas influxdb library are you using?

Comment: Michael - http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html